# PubSubHubbubについて教えて下さい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

https://github.com/igrigorik/PubSubHubbub

こちらのライブラリを使ってサイトをpub sub hub bubに対応したいと思いますが、1点わからないことがあります。

```
EventMachine.run {
  feeds = ["http://www.test.com", "http://www.test.com/2"]
  pub = EventMachine::PubSubHubbub.new('http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/publish').publish feeds

  pub.callback { puts "Successfully notified hub." }
  pub.errback  { puts "Uh oh, something broke: #{pub.response}" }
}
```

このサンプルの`feeds`という部分のURLはどのURLを指すのでしょうか。

- 更新したページのURL?
- RSS/ATOM feedのURL?
- サイトのトップページのURL?

それとも別のURLでしょうか・・・

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AtomとかRssとかXmlなfeedのURLです。　確認してみましょう。

与えられた配列は、hub.urlパラメータへ指定されます。
https://github.com/igrigorik/PubSubHubbub/blob/master/lib/pubsubhubbub/client.rb#L21

hub.urlパラメータは、
`hub.url equal to the feed URL of ...`
とあるように、フィードURLを指定するものです。
https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/
こちらのNotify the hub of new contentもご確認ください。
http://indiewebcamp.com/How_to_publish_and_consume_PubSubHubbub